# How do i make a static reference to a non-static method?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> original = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("afd", "asdf", "aavdd", "sajf", "adnf", "afd", "fjfn"));
    String find = "afd";
    String replaceWith = "asd";
    System.out.println(replaceIt(original, find, replaceWith));

  }
  public ArrayList<String> replaceIt(ArrayList<String> original, String find, String replaceWith){
      ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
      for(int y = 0; y<original.size(); i++){
        if(!original.get(y).equals(find))
          newList.set(y, original.get(y));
        newList.set(y, replaceWith);
      }
      
      original = newList;
      return original;
  }
}
```

How do i call the replaceIt method? I'm confused and I need to make it so it prints the output of that function. I'm so confused somebody please help.

Comment: Just make the method static, add static keyword to the method

Comment: instance methods belongs to objects and static method belongs to class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `public ArrayList<String> replaceIt()` is an instance method, it is only called from `Main` instances/objects.
- `public static void main` is a static method of class `Main`, static methods can’t access instance methods and instance variables directly.

Therefor, to call `replaceIt()` method from static main method, make `replaceIt()` static.

```
public static ArrayList<String> replaceIt(/*arguments*/){
    //your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having non-static method in `Main` is a little odd. It's not like you are going to construct new instances of Main (say, the same way you would construct new instances of a `Person` class).

These type of generic helpers/utils functions usually go into some sort `Utils.java` or `Helpers.java` class, and are declared as static in these files. This way you would be able to invoke: `Utils.replaceIt(original, find, replaceWith));`

Answer (score 0):

Because replaceIt() is an instance method, you simply need to create an instance of the Main class to call it -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    ...  
    Main m = new Main();  
    System.out.println(m.replaceIt(original, find, replaceWith));  
}
```